# Action bar spliting when not necessary

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have splitActionBarWhenNarrow option in my manifest.

In my first activity, the action bar should split and is spliting.

But when I call another activity from this activity the action bar shouldn't split, but she is splitting.

I made a lot of tests and I came to the conclusion that if the action bar is split in a activity, the others activity called will have the action bar split.

Is that conclusion right?

Ps: sorry for the bad english.

Comment: Format your Question properly and give sample codes, then this will become understandable for others .

Comment: Make sure that you have the `android:uiOptions` set on the `<activity>`, not the `<application>`, in the manifest.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight I was working and in a hurry, at night I will format the question properly, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set `android:uiOptions` on the `<application>`, it will affect all `<activity>` elements that do not specifically override it.

So, your options are:

1. Define it in `<application>` and use the split everywhere, or
2. Define it in `<application>` and also reset it in individual `<activity>` elements, to override it on a case-by-case basis, or
3. Only define it on `<activity>`, for those activities that you wish to use split action bars